# CSS Not Taking Effect on Page

Tags: html, css, cascading

I'm a new web design student and I just learned about Cascading Style sheets and how to link them externally; however, I'm encountering a problem. I have the file linked in my `<head>` with no problem and the file directory is correct, but my changes are not showing up. If I had a `<style>` tag or attribute then my CSS works, but not from the external file. Any help?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Protein Structures</title>
<link href="styles/main.css">
</head>
```

Comment: something css path problem plz check it

Comment: try `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I make this same mistake when I'm in a rush. The problem is, you're linking the file correctly, but the browser doesn't know how to interpret the file. Is it a stylesheet, icon, alternate stylesheet? You need to add the rel attribute and set it equal to stylesheet.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/main.css">
```

I'm not sure if type="text/css" is still mandatory. I know that when doing Javascript you don't have to have type="text/javascript".

Here's a good link [explaining](http://reference.sitepoint.com/html/link/rel) why.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add what the relationship of the link is. Change your `<link>` tag to:

```
<link href="styles/main.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

You might want to take a look at the documentation for [link types](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Link_types) to understand why the `rel` is necessary.

Answer (score 2):

try this i hope this is working.

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" media="all">
```